# ORA - 04020: deadlock detected while trying to lock object

Tags: oracle, plsql

Getting an `ORA-04020: deadlock detected while trying to lock object` and I believe the source of the error could be these statements:

```
  v_sql := 'DELETE FROM ' || in_table_name || ' SUBPARTITION (' || v_subpart_name || ')';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;

  v_sql := 'ALTER TABLE ' || in_table_name || ' TRUNCATE SUBPARTITION ' || v_subpart_name;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? Could it be the `ALTER` statement is throwing the error since the `DELETE` is right before it? Not sure, I thought the `ALTER` would execute only once the `DELETE` if finished. Or could it be the procedure doesn't wait for the `ALTER` to complete before exiting and re-executing?

Comment: It's probably because there is no commit, so the delete locks the rows.

Comment: You might find the following link helpful http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_04020_deadlock_detected_while_trying_to_lock_object_string.htm

Comment: I am facing this issue too in dev/production env. In my case, i am dropping 'sub partition' with 'UPDATE INDEXES'. I am getting it even when there is no other session performing any DML. Seems to be a 'Self Deadlocks' in my case. Will publish details once i crack it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your already doing TRUNCATE SUBPARTITION then why you need to delete . TRUNCATE would be much efficient way to delete data from table.

other wise you have to do commit after delete , then only truncate is allowed.

Regards
Ramki